# How to install pelican on a server to create mywebsite?

Tags: python, web, pelican

I want to install [pelican](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.4.0/) to create my online website. However, to install it on OVH server where my website is hosted, I need to run command lines but i can only host files and folders in **/www/** on my server. How can I install pelican in this case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to install Pelican on the server; it's meant to be installed on your local computer. Once installed locally, you generate your site and then transmit the output to your server. Many folks (myself included) use `rsync` to upload the generated HTML/CSS/JS to the server from which the site is actually served (OVH, in your case).

Once Pelican has been installed locally, you can run `pelican-quickstart` to create a skeleton project, answering the relevant questions for SSH/rsync. If you install Fabric as well, you can then edit the provided `fabfile.py` and run `fab publish` to automatically generate your site and transmit it to `/var/www/yoursite/`.